# How to start the second iteration of the revised simplex algorithm?

Tags: optimization, simplex-method

I converted the question into standard form by adding three slacks.
[image]

And I computed my first iteration:

[image]

I want to start my next iteration (iteration two, but I have problems)

[image]

I need to compute the new coefficient vector for my basis and calculate [[image: <span class=]$z^B$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0QMD.png)

How can I calculate $c^B$ to continue the problem? How to calculate the new coefficients for my basic variables and non-basic variables?